# Reading data in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

So my file has data of the form `full_file_path #` for example,

```
C:/dev/Java/src/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java 212
C:/dev/Java/src/java/util/HashMap.java 212
C:/dev/Java/src/java/lang/CharacterData02.java 190
C:/dev/Java/src/java/lang/CharacterData0E.java 190
C:/dev/Java/src/java/nio/DirectCharBufferS.java 123
C:/dev/Java/src/java/nio/DirectCharBufferU.java 123
...
```

and I'm trying to read the file with

```
int dup;
char file[MAX_LINE];
...
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("OUTPUT100.txt", "r");
while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", &file, &dup) == 1) {
   printf("%s %d\n", file, dup);
}
fclose(fp);
```

However the output is junk like

```
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
  RJ9 has 0 duplciate lines of code
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
  ▒▒" has 0 duplciate lines of code
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
  "A▒ has 0 duplciate lines of code
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
  7▒cw has 0 duplciate lines of code
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
   has 0 duplciate lines of code
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: My "still spits out junk" comments were just brain farts. I had a printf in a loop below the while loop that was spitting out junk. After scrolling up a few hundred lines I started seeing sensible data. Commenting out the printf resulted in the expected results. The working read uses `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", file, &dup) == 2)`. Thanks all.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", file, &dup) == 1)` No `&` before `file` it is already a pointer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it still spits out junk.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", file, &dup) == 2)` (sorry your match count was off too)

Comment: when calling `fopen(),  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the header file: `unistd.h` exposes the well known function: `dup()`.  The posted code does not meet the stackoverflow criteria of `small, cleanly compiles, has example of the problem` so, amongst other things, it is unknown if the `dup()` function is exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your loop call like this

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", file, &dup) == 2) {
```

As @mjswartz said `file` is an array that will decay to `char*` when you pass it to `fscanf`. Also `fscanf` will return the number of parameters it managed to retrieve and you are scanning 2 variables per line.

Comment: just tested your code with your file and it scans just fine. Where is this message "has 0 duplciate lines of code" getting printed from ? Do you have any filenames in "OUTPUT100.txt" with spaces in the name ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `fscanf` returns the number of successfull format specifiers so it will return 2 on success, and you're checking if it returns 1. You probably want to check for the `EOF` character instead and stop reading from there.

Also the `file` variable is an array which can be used as a pointer so you shouldn't try to reference it.

```
while (1)
{
    r = fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", file, &dup);
    if( r == EOF ) 
       break;
    printf("%s %d\n", file, dup);
}
```

Comment: In `C` doesn't `&` before an array name also give the address of the array? That is `file` and `&file` are the same values (but different types).

Comment: @kaylum the latter will be a pointer to a pointer which is redundant.

Comment: @Linus. Not it's not. It will be a pointer to an array type. In `C`, arrays are not the same as pointers (though can be used like pointers in many cases). It's a common misconception (though usually doesn't make a difference).

Comment: @kaylum you're right, I didn't realize he used such a array with the string constant, however it isn't necessary to pass a pointer to the array to `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", &file, &dup) == 1) {
```

the fscanf() returns the number of successful input/conversions

I.E. if it is successful, and the format string has 2 conversion parameters, then it will return 2, NOT 1.

Please read/understand the man page for `fscanf()`

The format string should NOT have a trailing '\n' (unlike printf() which almost always has a trailing '\n')

To consume any 'leftover' white space, like a newline, place a leading space in the format string.

The current format specifier '%s" does not have a max length modifier, so the data in the input file could overrun the available input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour that can lead to a seg fault event.

Note: in C, the name of an array degrades to a pointer to the first byte of the array, so do not take the address of the array: `file`

suggest:

```
while (fscanf(fp, " %#s %d\n", file, &dup) == 2) {
```

where `#` is the value MAX_LINE-1.

There is absolutely no possibility that the posted code output the text that is posted as the output.

Suggest posting the actual code, the actual output and the expected output.

Note: `file` is a poor name for an array of char.  suggest something meaningful, like `buffer`